How would a Hot Jupiter work in a P-Type Binary System?
This is my first time using the board so sorry for any mistakes.
I am currently designing a stellar System for my fantasy world. It is a P-Type Binary system which I have based upon a modified Keplar-35. I have used several sources online to help me with my research although I am fairly certain they are more broad approximations and while I try to get it realistic, I am no scientist.
Video-wise I looked at Artifexiand and Worldbuilding Corner. The former one for the general science as I think his approach seems better to me, the latter because he was one of the few I found talking about Binary systems. Here the two videos respectively:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t22MY6fhxog
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGyk3ftyr_c
I then went ahead and modified Artifexians Google Sheet with information of worldbuilding corner and this side where I am pretty sure corner also took his information from:
https://worldbuilding-workshop.fandom.com/wiki/Worldbuilding_Guide_Part_3:_Planetary_Systems#P-Type_Binary_System
I was further also reading some additional sides mostly for plausibility checks as I found the math rather hard and I am honestly not really into it especially when it would be prone to error.
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/521996/pdf
https://phys.org/news/2006-03-hot-jupiter-harbor-earth-like-planets.html
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/777/2/166
Now while this gave me a decent understanding of how P-Type systems work (assumed the information and calculations from Artifexian and co. are correct) I struggle to find a way to place a Hot Jupiter into my system, as I read that they orbit between 0.01 and 0.5 AU, yet when I calculate my outer deadzone, I reach a limit of ~0.6 AU.
This is my Google Sheets calculations, the P-Type Star is my page.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U9btpvjXWz2FjeFPIBIEdWjl9pRNCCptQ_WNtO7pqas/edit?usp=sharing
My general idea was, that the Hot Jupiter in my system formed very early beyond the frostline but then moved inwards, destabilizing the orbits of other planets and objects also propelling them further inwards.
While a bunch of material from the disc was expelled, this was counterbalanced by new material introduced from the outer areas(also bringing needed water to the inner system for my habitable world), leading to the formation of the Hot Jupiter, one slightly larger then Earth rocky planet, one earth-like planet in the habitable zone and a asteroid belt which formed partially from the construction that the hot Jupiter caused, as well as two remaining Gas giants beyond the inner System.
I don't know if this story makes sense though. So the System would be:
Dual Stars -> Hot Jupiter -> Rocky Planet -> Habitable World -> Space of former Planet -> Asteroid Belt -> Gas Giant1 -> Gas Giant2 -> Outer Asteroid Belt
So my Question is:
How could a Hot Jupiter get into a stable Orbit despite being within a Star's Deadzone so often?

For future reference, please be aware that you are allowed one and only one question per post. Asking multiple questions is literally a reason to close the question (click "close" and read "Needs More Focus").

Edited the question is that fine now ?

Replacing question marks with conjunctions doesn't solve the problem. I've edited the question to demonstrate. You may roll the edit back if you disapprove. Thanks.

Yea edit is fine with me now i am only hopeing for an answer

Use Kepler-47 instead
From your linked articles:

Figure 7 shows the narrow and empirical HZs of this system and the boundary of planetary stability at 0.19 AU.


Kepler 47 is host to two Neptune-sized planets b and c with semimajor axes of 0.29 AU and 0.99 AU, respectively (Orosz et al. 2012b).


Figure 7 and Table 6 also show that the outer boundaries of the narrow and empirical HZs of the system are slightly larger than 1.5 AU, indicating that the majority of the orbit of planet c in this system is in the HZ. We would like to note that being a Neptune-sized planet, Kepler 47c cannot be habitable. However, it may harbor terrestrial-class habitable moons and Trojan planets that may be able to develop and sustain conditions for habitability.

*Emphasis mine

you could also simply thrink the planet for the sake of storytelling. If there can be a Neptun, there can also be an Earth. Life on a titan-sized moon might be interesting, though :)
